# python 3.10 - no libpython3.10.so - pyinstaller fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am having a problem with pyinstaller with python 3.10.5 on Ubuntu 18.04. I built Python 3.10.5 from source.

When I run pyinstaller with 3.10 I get the error below. When I run with 3.6 I get:

08:32:09 44362 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
08:32:09 44394 INFO: Using Python library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0

Looking on my machine there is no libpython3.10m.so, so I wonder if this is the problem? (There is a libpython3.10.a)

Would having a libpython3.10m.so fix the problem?
Where do I get one from or how do I build one?

pyinstaller/python 3.10 errors:

```
INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 134, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 782, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 714, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/TOOLS/tools-helper-build-python3-linux/hosttools/python/maxwell_dm.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['maxwell_dm_gui/app_entry.py'],
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 501, in assemble
    self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 605, in _check_python_library
    python_lib = bindepend.get_python_library_path()
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 897, in get_python_library_path
    python_libname = findLibrary(name)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 775, in findLibrary
    lib = _which_library(name, paths)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 806, in _which_library
    for _path in os.listdir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib64'
```